# Windows Forms Control custom collection is crashing designer without reporting any error(s)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I put together a simple Windows Forms Control that's intended to collect a group of specific custom controls and present them, like a very simplified Ribbon.

There doesn't *seem* to be anything wrong with it, and the control is even open-able in a Designer window, but as soon as I try to add it to an actual Form, it causes Visual Studio to work quite hard for about half a minute, before all of VS crashes to the desktop.

There's no errors, no warnings, no alerts, just several seconds of grinding / unresponsiveness, then the desktop (with VS auto-restarting itself).

Can someone please tell me / point me in the direction of what I've done wrong with this Control? (or point me to some better means of debugging it)?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CobblestoneCommon.Controls
{
    public sealed class RibbonButtonCollection : Panel, IEnumerator<RibbonButton>
    {
        #region Properties
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private List<RibbonButton> _buttons = new List<RibbonButton>();
        private int _position = 0; // for IEnumerator
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public RibbonButtonCollection() : base()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.Name = "RibbonButtonCollection";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 800, 64 );
            this.AutoSize = false;
            base.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            base.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.Paint += this.RibbonButtonCollection_Paint;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size( 0, 0 ); // Will be interpreted by the accessor as (64,64)
            this.ResumeLayout();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Accessors
        public RibbonButton this[ int index ] => (index >= 0) && (index < Count) ? this._buttons[ index ] : null;

        public RibbonButton this[ string name ]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                {
                    int i = IndexOf( name );
                    return (i < 0) ? null : this[ i ];
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        new public Size Size
        {
            get => base.Size;
            set
            {
                int width = (int)Math.Ceiling( value.Width / 64M ) * 64;
                base.Size = new Size( Math.Max( width, 64 ), value.Height );
            }
        }

        new public AnchorStyles Anchor
        {
            get => AnchorStyles.None;
            set => base.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        }

        new public bool AutoSize
        {
            get => base.AutoSize;
            set => base.AutoSize = false;
        }

        public int Count => _buttons.Count;

        new public DockStyle Dock
        {
            get => base.Dock;
            set => base.Dock = (value == DockStyle.None) || (value == DockStyle.Fill) ? DockStyle.Top : value;
        }

        new public Size MinimumSize
        {
            get => base.MinimumSize;
            set => base.MinimumSize = new Size( Math.Max( value.Width, 64 ), Math.Max( value.Height, 64 ) );
        }

        // prevent designer from mucking with our Controls
        new private ControlCollection Controls => new ControlCollection(this); // base.Controls;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private int IndexOf( string name )
        {
            if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) )
            {
                int i = -1; while ( (++i < Count) && !_buttons[ i ].Name.Equals( name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) ;
                return (i < Count) ? i : -1;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public void Add( RibbonButton newButton )
        {
            if ( !(newButton is null) )
            {
                int i = IndexOf( newButton.Name );
                if ( i < 0 )
                {
                    this.SuspendLayout();
                    _buttons.Add( newButton );
                    this.Controls.Add( newButton );
                    this.ResumeLayout();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Add( string label, Image picture ) =>
            this.Add( new RibbonButton( label, picture ) );

        public void Remove( RibbonButton button )
        {
            if ( !(button is null) )
                Remove( button.Name );
        }

        public void Remove( string name )
        {
            if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) )
            {
                int i = IndexOf( name );
                if ( i >= 0 )
                    this.RemoveAt( i );
            }
        }

        public void RemoveAt( int index )
        {
            if ((index >= 0) && (index < Count))
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                RibbonButton b = this[ index ];
                this.Controls.Remove( this[ index ] );
                this._buttons.RemoveAt( index );
                b.Dispose();
                this.ResumeLayout();
            }
        }

        private void RibbonButtonCollection_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
        {
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            foreach (RibbonButton button in this)
            {
                button.Location = new Point( x, y );
                x += button.Width;
                if (x >= this.Width)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y += 64;
                }
                if ( y >= Height )
                    break;
            }
            base.OnPaint( e );
        }

        public RibbonButton[] ToArray() => _buttons.ToArray();
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator Support
        RibbonButton IEnumerator<RibbonButton>.Current => this._buttons[ this._position ];

        object IEnumerator.Current => this._buttons[ this._position ];

        public IEnumerator<RibbonButton> GetEnumerator() => this._buttons.GetEnumerator();

        bool IEnumerator.MoveNext() => (++this._position) < this.Count;

        void IEnumerator.Reset() => this._position = 0;

        private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls
        #endregion

        #region (from RibbonButtoncollection.Designer.cs)
        /// <summary>Clean up any resources being used.</summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if ( disposing && (components != null) )
            {
                components.Dispose();
                while (_buttons.Count > 0)
                    this.RemoveAt( 0 );
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

- Visual Studio is version 16.6.1
- .Net target framework is 4.8

Comment: Often it is the Paint code. Try to comment it out for testing..

Comment: Your button.paint seems to move the button, which could cause another paint call..endless loop, boom..!

Comment: @TaW -- I thought the whole purpose of the ```.SuspendLayout()``` and ```.ResumeLayout()`` calls was to prevent exactly that? 

Comment: Huh? No, a) they are meant to save time and b) none are in the Paint event..!?

Comment: I presumed the "save time" part encompassed NOT doing things like layout and rendering as/while controls were being defined / altered. In any event, if that's not the case, how can I programmatically ensure the desired arrangement of the child controls before it attempts to draw/paint the parent control, without ending up in this trap? 

Comment: The Paint event is strictly for adding drawings to the control, not for layout. In fact pretty much any layout will trigger a fresh paint call as the new layout will have to be painted. so, everything one sees is the combination of the base.Paint and your Paint events; both are all about painting pixels. - Arranging controls ie layout is to be done whenever it changes or is initialized. Use InitializeComponent for 1st layout and (I believe) Layout for later..

Comment: Also note that you can prevent both layout and drawing in the designer by testing whether you are in runtime or designer: `if (DesignMode)`. SuspendLayout is to stop drawing each item when you want to add many in a row..

Answer (score 1):

The way I debug these is to use Visual Studio to debug Visual Studio.

1. Open instance 1 of Visual Studio with all forms closed.
2. Open a second instance of VS.
3. From the second instance, select Debug -> Attach to Process. Select the first VS instance (devenv). The project name should be inluded in the Title to help you figure out which one you want.
4. Open the Exceptions window and check the option to break on all .Net exceptions.
5. Perform the action in instance 1 that causes the failure to occur.

If all goes well, instance 2 should enter a break condition and give you an indication of the source of your error.

Comment: Wow, what an interesting possibility! -- Doing this, it seems to be cycling through the ```RibbonButtonCollection_Paint()``` and ```base.OnPaint()``` until it blows through the stack. IDKY the panel's OnPaint function seems to trigger this classes Paint, and even putting in a trigger to abort the Paint procedure if it's called 2x doesn't stop the apparent infinite recursion... 

Comment: Glad that this could help. Identifying the problem is often the hardest part.